# Creating a custom layer and convolving it

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Consider the code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import layers

#input_features is given, and is 1x20x20x1000 for instance.
N_outputs = 200
N_intermediate = 50

out_lst = []
for i in xrange(N_outputs):
    net = layers.conv2d(
        input_features,
        N_intermediate, [1, 1]
    )
    out = layers.conv2d(
        net,
        1, [1, 1],
        activation_fn=None,
        normalizer_fn=None
    )

    out_lst.append(out)

logits = tf.concat(out_lst,axis = 3)
```

Overall the network should take an input of size 1x20x20x1000, and 
return output of size 1x20x20x200,  where each of the 200 output logits 
is passed through its own single layer of size N_intermediate.

The problem with this is that the graph construction is rather slow, and 
then it requires too much memory, resulting in memory error. 
For comparison, the following code

```
#input_features is given, and is 1x20x20x1000. 
N_outputs = 200
N_intermediate = 50

net = layers.conv2d(
        input_features,
        N_intermediate*N_outputs, [1, 1]
    )
net = layers.conv2d(
        net,
        N_outputs, [1, 1],
        activation_fn=None,
        normalizer_fn=None
)

logits = net
```

creates the graph and the training runs well, despite the fact that much more variables are created. 
The first version is equivalent to the second, with many weights set to 0 in the last layer (and they do have to be zero).

What is the best way to create a network equivalent to the one in the first version?

Comment: What kind of input do you use?

Comment: A 1x20x20x1000 tensor. Could be bigger, like 1x20x20x5000. It comes as an output of a  large rather deep network.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to accomplish. In the first case you create 200 layer objects and concatenate them, while in the second you create only 1 layer. You can try replacing for loop with `tf.contrib.layers.repeat`, but it's essentially the same, I don't think you'll get any improvement. If you add more info on your problem, maybe someone will propose a solution using low level constructions rather than layers api.

Comment: @Sharky :  I see. Maybe another way to describe the situation would be that in the second version of the code,  in the highest layer, we want each of the 200 outputs to depend not on all `N_intermediate*N_outputs` features of previous layer (as it is now), but only on `N_intermediate` of them (different `N_intermediated` subset for each of the 200), with the rest of the variables set to 0 and untrainable -- if its possible somehow to make only a part of a tensor untrainable.

Comment: You can try define each layer as a function with `tf.Variable` for weights and make some of them trainable by setting `trainable=True`, or define with layer function and pass only needed set of parameters to `optimizer.minimize`.
Have you seen how inception block is constructed? Maybe you're trying to accomplish something similar?

Comment: Will check out the inception blocks.